# Mission Control; how do I correct the order of Desktops? I have 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7?

Tags: macos, mission-control

I've been playing with Lion and Mission Control.  I'm not sure how I did it, but I seem to have reordered my desktops.

When I open Mission Control, the labels of the desktops at the top of the screen are (from left to right):

Dashboard, Desktop 1, Desktop 2, Desktop 4, Desktop 5, Desktop 3 (in the wrong place!), Desktop 6, Desktop 7, Desktop 8, Desktop 9

How did I relocate 3?  And how do I put it back in the right place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is this:

Delete the desktops and then recreate the by hovering over them and pressing the red thing in the corner, then looking at the right to make a new desktop.

---

This is no longer necessary as of Mac OS Lion 10.7.2, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18067/mission-control-how-do-i-correct-the-order-of-desktops-i-have-1-2-4-5-3-6/27568#27568) for an easier solution.

Comment: Thanks, deleting by clicking on the X for "Desktop 3" did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

By default, Spaces are reorganized by last used. You can change this in System Preferences -> Mission Control.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with Mac OS Lion 10.7.2, you can drag to re-order your desktops, even the ones that are in full-screen mode.

Comment: For future reference, [that's 10.7.2](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/10/12/apple-releases-os-x-10-7-2-with-icloud-support/).

Comment: *Except* desktop 1. Apparently it cannot be moved nor any other desktop can be made as new number one.

Comment: @koiyu No longer true in OSX 10.10.4.

Answer (score 5):

You can't drag or relocate them *even after you disable automatic ortanization* in System Preferences -> Mission Control.

They seem to be fixed, which is weird. Let's hope that in a future update, Apple *fixes* this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the windows displayed on the single desktops by pressing the alt key and then clicking on a desktop. So if for example you want preview (which was on desktop 3) to move to desktop 2 you would do:

> Alt + Click on Desktop 3 & Drag the Window of Preview and put in on
>   desktop 2.

Else you can also go to desktop 2 and right click on the Preview icon in the Dock and then click on: Assign to Desktop 2.